# Remove sidebar from specific page in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

i have one questing on what i need some help. I using [Advanced Classifieds & Directory Pro](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-classifieds-and-directory-pro/) plugin for inserting my listings. But plugin is using the same template as my blog template which i have modified a little. So now i want to remove sidebar just from this [listing/post page](http://echographie-sans-frontieres.com/acadp_listings/listing-3/) but to keep in blog page.

i tryed this:

```
.acadp_listings .sidebar .clearfix {display:none;}
```

but seems not remove sidebar just for listing page.. ANy help here?

Comment: check the body classes, you will for sure find a specific ID for that page

Comment: I don't know this plugin but try it with `.acadp_listings { display: none !important }`

Comment: I want to remove sidebar, not entire listing page.

Comment: Then use `.sidebar { display: none !important }`

Comment: As @TemaniAfif said every wordpress page has by default unique page id as class names, and in your case even your plugin might have their own different class there in template. Try to look after that and apply display: none; css to that particular class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using a theme, in general, the sidebar is defined by the template of the page, it's an option of the 'Page Attributes'. So, changing it to the default template you can disable the sidebar. You also could check the "customize" option of the page to see if there are something about the sidebar.

Comment: Page dont allow me select which template will use. It is using that by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the sidebar on your template, you will need to create a template file to override the current post archive, by creating a archive.php/home.php on your theme, see the template hierarchy docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Also you can modify the current template file and set a condition on where to or not to echo the sidebar.

```
<?php 
      if( is_archive() ){
            get_sidebar();
      }
?>
```

or create a custom page template and refer it on your 'page edit' > 'page attributes' > 'template', read documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Example: Create a page-list.php and upload to your theme folder.

```
<?php /* Template Name: No Sidebar Template */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="content">
            <h1><?php the_title( ); ?></h1>
            <?php the_content( ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

> The css will not remove the sidebar.

If you apply the `CSS`, it will only hide the sidebar, the sidebar will not be removed. So the DOM will render the content normally but the `CSS` will hide it from the user view.

Comment: Read underneath comment.

Comment: What then?... So, if you read the plugins [documentation](https://pluginsware.com/documentation/shortcodes/) it creates the pages and insert shortcodes on it to show the content, if you create a `page-listing.php` specifying the `Template Name:` and upload the file to your theme, you will be able to select the page template that you wanna load... See my updated answer.